# How do i create a Creating a document section / chapter template with decorative graphics

Tags: graphics

I am looking for guidance on how to create a document chapter / section template which includes standard decorative graphics.  For example lines with shaded boxes of text at the beginning of the line to use as a subsection heading.
Or a uniquely shaped shaded box with numeric annotation to act as  a paragraph marker.

I was hoping to be able to create each type of graphic in a dedicated file using Tikz code then place a reference to that code at each place in the document the graphic was intended to be placed.

Using this technique is it possible to place a block of "positioning placement" code to force the graphic to appear the intended page position, e.g. top right of left-justified, etc, etc.

Is Tikz the way to go or is thier a better solution?

Thanks in Advance
Tim C.

Comment: You can use `titlesec` for that. There are plenty of examples on this site. Just do a Google picture search for `site:tex.stackexchange.com tikz titlesec` to see examples.

Comment: Take a look to the `tcolorbox` manual.